# "if request.method == 'POST':" == False, but "if request.POST" == True. Why?- Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

When I use the following code, the first if statement always returns a False.  But if I change it to request.POST it will return a True.  Does anyone know why? Has anyone else experienced this? I'm sending it data using a basic form with method="post".

```
def add_new_user(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index_input(request)
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = NewUserForm()

    return render_to_response('appname/add_new_user.html',
        {'form': form}, context)
```

Comment: FYI, django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST) clearly say `you shouldn’t use if request.POST to check for use of the POST method`.

Comment: See also: http://buddylindsey.com/django-request-post-vs-request-method/

Comment: But request.post returns true and my form saves to the db.  It is request.method == "POST" that always returns false, no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

An empty dictionary will return `False` in Python, which is why `request.POST` would return `False` if there is no data in the POST QueryDict.

```
$ d = {}
$ d is True
$ False
```

Comment: but request.post is returning true.  request.method = post is returning false.

Comment: If there is data in the request.POST dictionary it will return `True`. request.method should check for an uppercase string: request.method == 'POST'

Comment: That works!  I do not know why it didn't work before.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: Every once in a blue moon, I have to delete a .pyc file that doesn't get re-compiled for some reason, and magically, things start working again.

Comment: Funny how computers need to be reset from time to time... and people too.